# Live text focusing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a program where I will type something in a input text field and it will show the current value of the text field at the span area. But the problem is, when I type first character, it shows nothing and when I type another one it shows the first one. But I want to exact same thing which is existed my text box. For example,

The Input field, if type 1, it shows nothing, then I type 2, it shows 1, but I want to show when I type 1, it will show 1 and when I type 2, it will show 12.

```
<script>
i = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").keypress(function(){
         $("span").text(this.value);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text">

<p>Keypresses: <span>0</span></p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look for the `keyup` event:

```
$("input").on('keyup', function () {
     $("span").text(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better use

```
 $("input").change(...
```

as event handler instead of `keypress`

Comment: This event will not fire on each typed character, as the questions requires.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple to implement without jQuery. The example uses the onkeyup event to ensure it captures the last key typed. onkeydown works too, but will be a character behind as OP already noted in the question.

**Example - Run snippet to test**

```html
<html>
<body>
  <input placeholder="enter some text" type="text" onKeyup="this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = this.value">
  <span style="color: blue;"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will it support all browsers that jQuery supports?

Comment: Would need to check browser compatibility of "nextElementSibling".  All modern browsers for sure.

Comment: And that's one of jQuerys benefits :-)

Comment: It could be replaced with getElementById() which works in IE5 and older ... if you really need to support very old browsers.

Comment: Yeah but an ID can only be used once per page.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the `keypress` event is fired BEFORE the value has changed, so the span is setting the value that is know at that moment.

Different than what another user mentions, you can't use the `change` event as a trigger (fired at the end of the operation) since it might not trigger until you remove the focus from the input.

Using `keyup` would provide the desired behavior.